# Kubernetes Dashboard does not have user icon on top right

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have deployed Kubernetes Dashboard v2.0.4 using Helm on my Azure Kubernetes Service cluster. For some reason I don't have the user icon on the top right of the page and I'm automatically login to the dashboard with minimal access.

I can give myself admin access by creating a clusterRoleBinding between the serviceAccount created during the dashboard installation and the cluster-admin role but I want to be able to provide a token without having to bind it directly to the dashboard's serviceAccount.

Here's a screenshot from Azure's Kubernetes Dashboad add-on where you can see the user icon I'm talking about:
[Azure's Kubernetes Dashboad add-on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eD3nl.jpg)

Here's a screenshot from my dashboard where there isn't a user icon: [My dashboard page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32L6e.jpg)

Here's the Helm command I used to install the dashboard:

`helm install my-dashboard k8s-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard --version 3.0.0 --set=service.externalPort=80 --set=protocolHttp=true --set=metricsScraper.enabled=true -n my-namespace`

I'm also using nginx ingress to access to the dashboard.

I don't know if I mistakenly changed a configuration somewhere to bind the cluster-admin role token permanently to the dashboard's service account but after deleting and re-installing the Helm chart, I'm still not able to logout and provide a token.

Any idea why this occurs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would say you from the begging - I havent reproduced you question - answering based on my prev knowledge.

Can you please specify exact repo you used for kubernetes-dashboard installation?

The proper ways of accessing dashboard via bearer token are

- grant cluster-admin role to dashboard servicaccount

or

- you can create separate cluster admin account if you dont want to grant the access to default one

```
---#create SA
$ kubectl create serviceaccount cluster-admin-dashboard-sa
$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-dashboard-sa \
  --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
  --serviceaccount=default:cluster-admin-dashboard-sa

---#retrieve token
$ kubectl get secret | grep cluster-admin-dashboard-sa
cluster-admin-dashboard-sa-token-6xm8l   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3         18m
$ kubectl describe secret cluster-admin-dashboard-sa-token-6xm8l
```

Above approach is not counted as secure one, so please consider using other available authentication methods while work with production servers.

[Use the AKS Kubernetes dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-dashboard) also shows you the way to set up and configure kubernetes dashboard.

Also few tips.

- I always use latest [kubernetes/dashboard](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard) documentation and steps for GCP dashboards. There is no helm there, you simply install with `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.4/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml` and accessing using Authentication Token
- talking about Azure - I prefer to start dashboard using provided  command in doc
  `az aks browse --resource-group yourResourceGroup --name yourCluster`

Clear all cache after redeploying before accessing dashboard. Also check if helm wipes all prev resources upon deletion/re-installation.

If that doesnt work - can you try to access dashboard using kubeconfig(modified for your newly created user)